# What are the recent real life use or applications of the Cauchy Random Variable?

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, cauchy-distribution

We have a short assignment on the described question and I already have gone through a lot of trash results from Google. I can't seem to find any.

I don't know where else to post this question. Please guide me! It will be a great help.

I was asked from [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650772/what-are-the-recent-real-life-use-or-applications-of-the-cauchy-random-variable) to post here.

Comment: Weakly informative prior distributions of parameters in Bayesian models. Gelman a paper on this re: logistic regression.

Comment: It might help to recognize this as having a Student t distribution :-).

Answer (score 2):

Cauchy distribution is also called Breit-Wigner or Lorentz distribution. It's used a lot in [physics](http://www.thespectroscopynet.eu/?Physical_Background:Atomic_Emission_Lines_Shapes:Lorentz_lineshape), particularly [spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line_shape#Line_shape_functions).